# Why is $f(n) = n^3$ not an onto function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I was doing an example  in a book where it asked which of these functions are one to one, the answer in the back said for $f(n) = n^3$ that it is a one to one function. Then it asked which of the functions from the previous example are onto and $f(n) = n^3$ was not included in the list of onto functions.

In a later example, a question asked which of these functions is a bijection, the answer included $f(x) = x^3$.

This is confusing because doesn't a function have to be both an onto and one to one to be a bijection? Why would the book say it was not a onto in a previous example yet declare it to be a bijection? Is the book wrong?

Comment: HInt. Is the domain the real numbers or the integers?

Comment: How did you define the $f$? That function $f$ must be define from a set into another set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never attempt to answer if a function is one-to-one or onto without first knowing the domain and codomain.

For example the function
$$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\quad f(x) = x^2$$
is neither one-to-one ($1$ and $-1$ both map to $1$) or onto (nothing maps to e.g. $-1$).

The function
$$g:\mathbb{[0,\infty)}\to [0,\infty),\quad g(x) = x^2$$
is both one-to-one and onto.

We have only changed the domain and codomain, and this changed the properties of one-to-one and onto.

Comment: Oh yeah I totally forgot to check the domain, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Check the domain of the function in both the questions as a prerequisite**.

> The function $f (n)=n^3$ **is onto** if $f (n): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. If it helps, see [here](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xto1over3.svg).